# Duda: quitar espacio en blanco una cadena sin usar replace

Tags: java

Tengo que hacer lo siguiente:

**Realiza una función que reciba una cadena y devuelva otra cadena igual pero sin espacios en blanco. No se pueden utilizar métodos replace.**

Sé que se hace con un bucle `for` y un `charAt` pero llevo un buen rato intentándolo y no consigo hacerlo, alguna ayuda?

Comment: Amigo añade parte del codigo fuente please

Answer (score 1):

Hola te dejo un ejemplo de como lo puedes hacer.

```
public static void main(String[] args){

        String str = "texto aquí";
        String retorno ="";
        for (int n = 0; n<str.length (); n++) { 
            char c = str.charAt (n); 
            if(!(" ").equals(Character.toString(c)))
                retorno+=Character.toString(c);
        }
        System.out.println (retorno); 
}
```

saludos

Answer (score 0):

El código sería algo como esto:

```
public class Reemplazo 
{

        public static void main(String[] args) {
                System.out.println("Hola que tal");
                System.out.println(sinBlancos("hola que tal"));
        }

        public static String sinBlancos(String cadena)
        {
                String nueva = "";
                for(int x=0; x < cadena.length(); x++)
                {
                        if(cadena.charAt(x) != ' ')
                        {
                                nueva = nueva + cadena.charAt(x);
                        }
                }
                return nueva;
        }
}
```

Comment: jajaja menudo plan, dos respuestas prácticamente iguales XDD